# How can I execute an external application from a C++ program that continues to run after the calling program exits?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to run an external application that will continue to run after the calling application exits.  I have successfully done this with a variety of methods but the problem is that even though the calling application is no longer running, the new executable is still "attached" to it.  This is seen if the calling application is run from a USB drive.  If the external application (started from the calling application) is running I cannot eject the USB.  If I close the external application I can successfully eject the USB.  I've tried using CreateProcess, ShellExecute and ShellExecuteEx but they all have the same problem.  I also need to start the external application in a minimized state.  Am I missing something in the call or failing to clean up correctly after a call?  I am using C++

Thanks,
Rhonda

Comment: The issue is with the current working directory when the external application was executed. You should try `chdir()` to change the current directory outside of USB before executing the external application.

Comment: Kindly Format your Question...

Comment: Have you tried changing the working directory of the child process to see if that will allow you to eject the USB drive?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  This does not solve the problem.  I think there must be some leftover connect to the process I'm starting.  I'm thinking there is something I need to do after the call to clean it up and break the connect.